# Flex Mobile Project: Alert.show

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, alert

I wanna use Alert dialog box instead of skinnable container in my mobile application. I imported Alert class like:

```
import mx.controls.Alert;
```

and then I wrote the code below in my button click handler:

```
Alert.show("example","Error!",Alert.OK);
```

but when I wrote this code I got lots of errors whose codes are 1120 and 1172, e.g.,

```
"Access of undefined property ButtonSkin".
```

If I do not write this code, there is no problem. My application works fully.

Any idea about this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Alert is not available in a mobile project; how did you import it w/o a compiler error?  [I suspect it was one of the many errors you said you got]

You'll probably want to look into using the [PopUpManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html) to position a [SkinnablePopUpContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS67cd75b2532ad652-1abb110512d5bda966d-8000.html).

Comment: I imported Alert class by adding mx.swc into my application. But I saw that it does not work correctly. I had used SkinnablePopUpContainer and it worked. In fact, my real problem is that the popupcontainer cannot come to screen like in iphone or ipad in terms of easing, tweening and its skin.

Comment: @user1093794 I don't know what you mean by "Come to screen" .  It is strongly recommended you do not use the mx.swc in mobile apps for performance reasons.  To clear your ButtonSkin error you'll also have to add the spark theme into your app.

Comment: Thanks www.Flextras.com. Think about an alert box opened in any application in iphone,e.g.,when you delete something. It has motion tween,backEaseOut. I'd like to do the same thing for my SkinnablePopUpContainer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-development-tips-tricks-pt4.html

This would be an easier solution, It has skinned Alerts and normal Alerts which can be used in a mobile project.